# UML state diagram for N number of approvals

Tags: c#, uml, state-diagram

I am writing my first state diagram for an approvals matrix and I am stuck. An Order in our system will go through a number of states and transitions for approval:

States

- **Start (state)**
- (submit() transition)
- **Awaiting Approval (state)**
- *(approve() transition)*
- **Awaiting Approval (state)**
- *(approve() transition)*
- ...
- **Live (state)**

My problem is that the awaiting approval states will only transition to Live state when N number of approve() events, for each order, are received (an approval from one user will trigger a notification for approval from another user).

Should I add a decision point after the Awaiting Approval state that does a self transition back to Awaiting Approval OR progresses to Live state based on a count of approvals *(is that allowed? Or am I missing something?)*

Any help would be appreciated. Most state diagrams I look at are based on a set number of approvals, not a variable list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will add a guard:

[image]

The `approval` trigger has a behavior `inc approval count`. Now the guard `[approval count > N]` will pass only if the counter is great enough.

Comment: thanks for this, I was worried about a guard because I wasn't sure if guards were for preventing leaving a state, even on self transitions

Comment: You could clarify this to 100% by adding `[approval count <= N]` as guard to the self-transition. But honestly, this way it should already be obvious.